# Create filesystem cache with Axios to cache API requests in global

Tags: node.js, axios

I want to cache some API requests with axios, save the cache for 30min and show the cache results for every user in the site without load the request again till the cache expired.

so if I load data from URL `http://localhost/test` the next request will show the data from the filesystem cache only, so the load time will be 0s and the results will be static for 30min.

Using nodejs with nuxt.

I tried to install Redis but got errors with node-gyp & hiredis -
`WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.node-gyp/12.13.1"`

There is some tool that can help with that? or I need to develop it in myself?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I made some changes, do you need more information?

Comment: I haven't used axios but as an http client i doubt it handles caching (but check the docs and don't take my word for it); so you will need to implement that either from scratch using the node process' in-memory cache though this is volatile because you will lose it if the process dies, or use another more reliable/scalable caching technology such as redis or memcached. Whatever you go for do plenty of research and be aware of the pitfalls https://codeahoy.com/2017/08/11/caching-strategies-and-how-to-choose-the-right-one/

Comment: Yes i tried Redis, but there is some error mentioned above.

Comment: Work through redis install docs and then search the internet for any errors - most likely the problems you're encountering have been encountered by others before then if you cannot find a solution ask back here.

Comment: Already tried few possible solutions yesterday and in the morning today, nothing worked.. i tried everything.. even reinstall NodeJS, also i tried via windows & ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You can use in-memory cache or a redis client to store the result, you will then need to access the data from this cache, here is the npm package and an example of using a redis cache - https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-cache-adapter#use-redis-as-cache-store

Comment: Hey, i tried use Redis via this link earlier, got errors in `hiredis` & `node-gyp` in ubuntu.. still not have fix for the issue.. tried a lot of possible solutions..